# How to register all services at once using Unity.Mvc5

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, dependency-resolver

please help me to register all services and repositories at once using [Unity.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/).

I'm using below scenario now. but in this I have to register every single service and repository to unity container.

Is there any way to register all services and repository by scanning assembly (like provided by StructureMap or Lamar)
Or something else.

Thanks In advance :).

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
container.RegisterType<IAbcRepository, AbcRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IAbcService, AbcService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a question here.
below code is working as expected.

There is any drawback of this and will create any issue in future? or any best way to register all repositories and services except this?

```
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            // container.RegisterType<IAbcRepository, AbcRepository>();
            // container.RegisterType<IAbcService, AbcService>();

            container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(Repository).Assembly), WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, GetName, GetLifetimeManager);
            container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(Service).Assembly), WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, GetName, GetLifetimeManager);
        }


        static bool IsNotificationHandler(Type type)
        {
            return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType);
        }

        static LifetimeManager GetLifetimeManager(Type type)
        {
            return IsNotificationHandler(type) ? new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() : null;
        }

        static string GetName(Type type)
        {
            return IsNotificationHandler(type) ? string.Format("HandlerFor" + type.Name) : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

How much is this safe to use in a large application?